# Write to locked file regardless of lock status

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to write to a locked file regardless of what program/process has it open?

Scenario:

- A commercial product running as a service, locks a log file.
- Service can not be stopped because it will impact customers.
- Would like to inject a line at the end of the file as a marker.

Getting error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Is there ANY way to append a line on a locked file?

Also, afraid of breaking the lock status, as it may cause the commercial program to break.

Originally thinking batch file until finding out log file is locked. Will do powershell or whatever language can pull this off.

Comment: There's a good chance that no matter what you do, the program that holds the lock will just overwrite your marker because it's file position pointer is before it when it goes to write.

Comment: No. And as @David said, if you did it would end up being overwritten anyway. Think about it: I've got the file open and write 10 bytes, and you write a line of text at the end of the file. I still think the end of the file is at byte 10, and write my next line starting at byte 11 (overwriting the line you added). File locks are there for a reason - to prevent others from accessing the file while you have it locked.

Comment: Thank David and Ken, good point. Was hoping file would be locked, but they are just appending. But if it's locked, then it's probably using file pointers instead of appending. Any way to add a line just to see what happens?

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to edit it outside of the lock, send a message to your process that has locked the file, and have it receive that message and add this "marker" at the position described in your message. There's a reason messages exist, this is exactly it.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, the whole idea of the lock(ed) file is that the process that has the lock does not have to worry about other processes modifying the file, so the lock owner does not have to query the file system all the time and can do it's operations much more efficiently.
And see earlier comments by "David Schwartz" and "Ken White"