# Writing to a file with QFile fails, without error code, when already opened in Excel

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qfile

I try to write to an existing file with QFile, which works as expected. However, the problem is that if the file is open in Excel, writing to the file from my program fails.

I try to test the permissions with QFileInfo and have all read and write permissions on the file. The test

```
bool opened = file-> open (QIODevice :: WriteOnly)
```

returns true.

The same problem does not occur when the file is opened with notepad++.

How can I check if the file is locked and can't be written to?

Comment: Excel certainly put a lock on the file that notepad++ don't do.

Comment: Notepad++ most probably closes the file after loading and doesn't keep it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel locks its open files for exclusive use. You can't write to an open file, move or delete it. There is no way to bypass this lock.

See also: [Write to locked file regardless of lock status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169349/write-to-locked-file-regardless-of-lock-status)

Comment: Thank you for your quick and clear answer, is there a way to know if the file is blocked by Excel.

Comment: `QFile::open` should return false. It is so for me, I've checked it. May be on some systems or configurations it can return true, but then `write` should return an error. You should check both `open` and `write` return values to ensure that the file is saved properly.

Comment: I dont't use QFile to write I use it juste for open my file and for writing i use QTextStream, here's a tip of my code 
        QFile *file=new QFile("my file");
        bool opened=file->open (QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        if  (!opened) {
            qDebug()<<"write open ERROR" ;
        }
        QTextStream    *flux=new QTextStream(file);
        *flux << "text to write "<<endl;
        file->close (); i will see if i can to use QFile::Write

Comment: You can use `QTextStream::status` method to check for errors. Also note that in you case there is no point in using `new` for `file` variable. Use `QFile file("my_file");` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I replace QTextStream with QFile :: write and it seems to work well, and I also added the treatment of QFile :: write return in case of problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the QFile::write function, it returns the number of bytes written, or -1 if an error occurred.

If you check the return code from the write function, you should be able to use that to determine that the file is locked by another process.

Calling QFile::open returns without error, because you can still get a valid handle to the file, even though another process has locked it, preventing you writing to it at the same time.

Comment: the return code will be -1, and not very useful. errno might work, and checking the file's errorString(). The latter only gives a human-readable error string, nothing one should analyze in code.

Comment: Thanks for responses, finally I use QFile::write instead of using QtextStream to write in file.